# How to change the name of a macOS app within the app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The usual way to change the name of an app would simply to rename the project name in Xcode

[image]

but can you change the name directly *inside* the app with a textfield? is that possible?

```
TextField("Change App Name", text: $appname)
```

Comment: No, (fortunately) it's not possible. You can provide localized names, but this must be specified in the application bundle at compile time too.

Comment: For what it's worth, `ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName` is `{ get set }`, which means you *can* set it's value.  Whether that will have any visible effect, like changing the name in the main menu, or altering how it appears in `top` or `Activity Monitor`, I have no idea.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just tried setting `ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName` in the starter App Xcode creates when you create a new macOS app project.  I could see no effect at all, except that when I print `ProcessInfo.processInfo.processName` it prints the value I set.  But the main menu remains unchanged, so does it's `ps` listing, and in `Activity Monitor`.  If setting it has any useful effect, I didn't find it in my quick test.